# Panel background paint not working

Tags: c#, winforms, gradient, paint

I have been doing the borders of my winforms with panels. I wanted to use a gradient in my bottom panel but I´m having a problem.

I´m using almost the same method that i used to paint my form´s background here, but I get a red cross in the panel. I dont know why this is happening, it should work fine.

Image: [image]

This is my code to paint:

```
public void Colorear_Barra_abajo(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle r = this.ClientRectangle;

        if (r.Width > 0 && r.Height > 0)
        {
            Color c1 = Color.FromArgb(255, 54, 54, 54);
            Color c2 = Color.FromArgb(255, 98, 98, 98);

            LinearGradientBrush br = new LinearGradientBrush(r, c1, c2, 90, true);
            ColorBlend cb = new ColorBlend();
            cb.Positions = new[] { (float)0.357, (float)0.914 };
            cb.Colors = new[] { c1, c2 };
            br.InterpolationColors = cb;

            // paint
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, r);
        }
    }
```

And this is how i call it (panel_Borde_abajo is the panel):

```
public Base_Form_Standard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel_Borde_abajo.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Colorear_Barra_abajo);
    }
```

I used to use this methods to paint other controls others than forms (menustrip f.e) and they worked fine, but this particulary one isn´t working.

This, for example does works properly and no red cross appears:

```
public void Form_Background(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle r = this.ClientRectangle;

        if (r.Width > 0 && r.Height > 0)
        {
            Color c1 = Color.FromArgb(255, 252, 254, 255);
            Color c2 = Color.FromArgb(255, 247, 251, 253);
            Color c3 = Color.FromArgb(255, 228, 239, 247);
            Color c4 = Color.FromArgb(255, 217, 228, 238);
            Color c5 = Color.FromArgb(255, 177, 198, 215);

            LinearGradientBrush br = new LinearGradientBrush(r, c1, c5, 90, true);
            ColorBlend cb = new ColorBlend();
            cb.Positions = new[] { 0, (float)0.3, (float)0.486, (float)0.786, 1 };
            cb.Colors = new[] { c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 };
            br.InterpolationColors = cb;

            // paint
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, r);
        }
    }
```

Please if somebody could help me it will be great!

Comment: The red cross indicates that your paint method bombed with an exception.  You debug that with Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkbox for CLR exceptions.  You'll then discover the problem with the ColorBlend object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks, that you have used invalid values for a **ColorBlend.Positions** property, try this code:

```
ColorBlend cb = new ColorBlend();
cb.Positions = new[] { 0.0f, 0.357f, 0.914f, 1.0f };
                       ^^^^                  ^^^^
```

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.colorblend.positions.aspx):

> The elements in this array are represented by float values
>   between 0.0f and 1.0f, and the first element of the array must be 0.0f
>   and the last element must be 1.0f.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I must add two more colors now, so I used the same first color in 0, and repeated the last one in 1. But I´m not getting the same gradient as my WPF equivalent. The good news is that at least this is working.

Comment: Warlock, you solved my problem, but i have a question. I think that when i use "Rectangle r = this.ClientRectangle;" it is taking the size of the form and not from my panel. Maybe thats the reason I´m not getting the gradient correctly.

Comment: Yes, I think, that a key word "this" is related to the Form. In this case "this.ClientRectangle" returns a rectangle that represents a client area of the Form (not a panel).

Comment: Yes, i´m actually getting the size of the form there. I changed it now to the panel size and works properly. Thank you again!